# wxPython - PlateButton stopping wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN event

Tags: events, wxpython

In my app, when I press that PlateButton, the wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN stop working. I don't know what's going on. If I erase the bmpImage code and set the parent of the PlateButton to self, the event doesn't even fire in the first place.

Thanks!

```
import wx
import wx.lib.platebtn as pb

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)

    def initUI(self):
        bmpImage = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        bmpImage.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('image.JPG', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))

        btn = pb.PlateButton(bmpImage, -1, 'Click Me!', style=pb.PB_STYLE_NOBG)

    def OnKey(self, event):

        print('Key pressed!')
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Try binding the `btn` to OnKey for `EVT_KEY_DOWN` as well. Because it's capable of having dropdown menus, I suspect the platebutton is grabbing the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following code, you'll see that the platebutton is grabbing the event and obviously not skipping the event, thus it is not available to the frame, which you are binding to.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.platebtn as pb

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)

    def initUI(self):
        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Key Test", pos=(10, 10))
        btn = pb.PlateButton(self, -1, 'Click Me!', pos=(10,40), size=(100,25))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)

    def OnKey(self, event):
        print(event.GetEventObject())
        print('Key pressed!')
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It took me a little while to get it. Binding the PlateButton to the EVT_KEY_DOWN too did the trick. I'm not sure if this is an expected behaviour.